# Inserting bullet (Chr(183) or Chr(149)) in Word doc using VBA results in very small bullet

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm using Access VBA code like the following to create a Word doc and insert some formatted text.

One thing I need to do is separate some metadata with a bullet symbol.  We do this currently in an Access Report (where we use the symbol explicitly in the Access SQL statement that builds the data for the report), but now need to build a different type of document using VBA.

My research suggests that the bullet is Character Code 183 or 149, but when we use both of those in our VBA code, it inserts small bullets instead of the beefy bullet that we can get from inserting a bullet symbol directly through the Insert>Symbol menu.

Below is some example code, and a screen shot from the output of that code (with the last line manually added to show the size of the bullet we can add manually).  Any suggestions on how we can get a big bullet through VBA code?

```
' declare vars and set up

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim WordHeaderFooter As HeaderFooter
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

' create doc and insert sample text

    With objWord
        
        .Visible = True
    
        Set doc = .Documents.Add
        doc.SaveAs CurrentProject.Path & "\TestDoc.doc"
        
    End With
                  
    With objWord.Selection
          
        .Font.Name = "Calibri (Body)"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .TypeText "Here is an example test line with Chr 183.  Date: " & Format(Now(), "Long Date") & " " & Chr(183) & " Time: " & Format(Now(), "Medium Time")
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeText "Here is an example test line with Chr 149.  Date: " & Format(Now(), "Long Date") & " " & Chr(149) & " Time: " & Format(Now(), "Medium Time")
        .TypeParagraph
      
    End With
    
    doc.Save
    doc.Activate
```

[image]

Comment: A quick recorded macro returns `Selection.InsertSymbol CharacterNumber:=8226, Unicode:=True`. Have you tried it?

Comment: I might need some help.  I don't think unicode works in Chr(), but I tried 8226 in ChrW() (not sure if they work in that either), and I still get a tiny bullet.

Comment: P.S., I checked that if I do Chr(8226), that throws an error.

Comment: You approach to Word automation is poor. Instead of brute-force formatting you really should take the time to learn how to use Styles, which are fundamental to the way Word works. you use of Selection only compounds the poor coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your string, insert the symbol in between and then the time.

Try this:

```
With objWord.Selection
      
    .Font.Name = "Calibri (Body)"
    .Font.Size = 12
    .TypeText "Here is an example test line with Chr 183.  Date: " & Format(Now(), "Long Date") & " "
    .InsertSymbol CharacterNumber:=8226, Unicode:=True
    .TypeText " Time: " & Format(Now(), "Medium Time")
    .TypeParagraph
  
End With
```

It produces this:

[image]

Comment: If anyone knows, I'd be curious why ChrW doesn't work here.  It's supposed to return unicode symbols, no?  So why does it return a smaller version than the actual sumbol for 8226?

Comment: Well, I tried in a word document and it works. `Selection.TypeText "abc " & ChrW(8226)`.

Comment: Ok, weird.  It's definitely a tiny bullet for me.